# Change the Fill Color of a cell if the value of that cell equals the value of another specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I want to change the **fill color** of cell C5 if it has the same value as cell A5.

Can this be done? I know how to format cell C5 if it has a certain value - but not when it is to be compared to the value of another cell.

Answer (score 6):

Select the C5 cell and go to Home, Conditional Formatting. Choose "Manage Rules" and create a New Rule.

The new rule type is "format only cells that contain". The Rule Description should be "Cell Value equal to =$A$5". Then set the formatting you'd like on the cell.

[image: Formatting Rule:]

Comment: ok-but the value in C5 is =A5-because I want to have it the same information. So the formatting will not work-right? Is there a way to accomplish this? Cell A5 has a value of "Shared drives" (as an example) I want cell C5 to display the same information "Shared drives" AND to be color filled.

Comment: You could try highlighting the A and C columns, then going to Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values. But then it's going to highlight both columns.


Honestly, it's kind of hard to tell what exactly you want, as you haven't really explained the what/why of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Initially I want C5 to display the same value as A5 (Example-A5=”server” and C5=”server”) so in C5 I have “=A5” and A5 contains “server”. Since a user can change the value for C5 (Example A5=“server” and C5=”router”) I want C5 to color fill if it is the same as A5. But I think in the conditional formatting it is comparing values for (A5) “server” to (C5) “=A5” and since the values are not equal it will not color fill. I am sure there is a way to accomplish this, just not sure how. Hopefully I have explained better so it is understandable.

Comment: So then you could just change what I posted above to be "Cell Value NOT EQUAL TO =$A$5". That should color the cell when it doesn't equal the A5 value.

Comment: you are correct-I got it. Thanks...one more question. Is it possible to create a rule to highlight a range of cells if there is no value in the cell? So for cells A5:A20-if there cell is empty highlight it in yellow

Comment: Yup, instead of choosing "Cell Value" like above, choose "Blanks" to format only blank cells. Alternatively you can set a formula to "=isblank(A1)" or set A1 to your range.