# changing a cell's background color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How would you go about changing one particular cell's background color based on the content of multiple cells in the same row? For example:
I would like for A1's background color to become red when cell A2 has a value of 1.5 or greater. I would also like for A1 to turn yellow when A3 has the letter "H" and A2 is greater than or equal to 1.5. Thirdly, I would like for A1 to turn green when A4 has the letters "SB", A3 has the letter "H" and A2 is greater than or equal to 1.5.

Comment: use conditional formatting

Comment: Use *multiple* conditional formatting. Visit this link to learn how to manage conditional formatting precedence/priority: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-063cde21-516e-45ca-83f5-8e8126076249?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Fill Color of a cell if the value of that cell equals the value of another specific cell](https://superuser.com/questions/564815/change-the-fill-color-of-a-cell-if-the-value-of-that-cell-equals-the-value-of-an)

Comment: The proposed duplicate only covers the first example, not the other two. For this reason, I don't think this question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is known as Conditional Formatting to make a new conditional formatting rule click on the cell you wish to format and go to the *Home* tab, then click the *Conditional Formatting* drop down and click *New Rule*.

In there select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and for your first condition enter `=$A$2 >= 1.5` and select your color. You can do this for the other conditions. It should look like the image below.

[Creating a New Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYejD.png)

The next two conditional formatting rules are `=AND($A$2 >= 1.5, $A$3 = "H")` and `=AND($A$2 >= 1.5, $A$3 = "H", $A$4 = "SB")`.

If you enter the rules in the order you typed it out in the question you will have no problems. However let's say you want the yellow condition to have more importance over the green, you can change the conditional formatting rule precedence.

Click the *Conditional Formatting* drop down menu and then click *Manage Rules...*. In here you can change the order of each rule with the rule on having more precedence than the one(s) below.

[Rule Precedence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji8Lt.png)